# Convert text fractions to proper format in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, equation-editor

I inherited a large PPTX file with lecture slides. A lot of these have equations 'inline' with the text in the form z=x/y. I've been converting these to 'proper' equation format by highlighting them and clicking the Equation Editor button. But it doesn't convert them to 'proper' fractions, with the numerator on top and the denominator underneath. To do that, I have to insert a fraction and manually type them (or copy and paste). Is there a quicker way?

Basically, I want a method in Equation Editor to convert x/y to

x
_
y

(Sorry for the awful formatting - is there a way to put maths in?)